# Как реализовать вращение объектов внутри графической сцены QGraphicsScene?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Пишу простой графический редактор на Qt C++. Размещаю объекты `QGraphicsItem` на графической сцене `QGraphicsScene`. Необходимо реализовать вращение этих объектов внутри сцены при нажатии на соответствующее действие в меню. Проблеме в том, что использовать функцию `void QGraphicsItem::rotate ( qreal angle )`, так как она позволяет вращать объект лишь вокруг точки `(0,0)` графической сцены. Я хочу, чтобы объект мог вращаться вокруг своего центра. Пытаюсь реализовать это с помощью `setTransform`, однако в этом случае вращение выполняется единожды, и при повторном нажатии кнопки поворота не происходит.

Как мне это исправить?

Код функции, вызываемой из слота:

```
bool PaintScene::rotateObject()
{
    foreach (QGraphicsItem *item, selectedItems()){
        QPointF point1;
        QPointF point2;
        point1 = item->mapFromScene(item->boundingRect().topLeft());
        point2 = item->mapFromScene(item->boundingRect().bottomRight());
        x_mid = point2.x() - ((point2.x()-point1.x())/2);
        y_mid = point2.y() - ((point2.y()-point1.y())/2);
        item->setTransform(QTransform().translate(x_mid, y_mid).rotate(30).translate(-x_mid, -y_mid));
        item->rotate(30);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В идеале, нужно строить каждый объект в системе координат, в которой центр вращения находится в точке (0,0) (т.е. нужно помнить начальные параметры геометрии), а при каждой отрисовке сначала изменять масштаб (если нужно), затем вращать, и только после этого перемещать.
Если вращать нужно относительно текущего угла наклона, можно переместить в (0,0), затем повернуть, затем переместить обратно (или получить текущую матрицу преобразования, повернуть её, затем применить к объекту)

Конкретно в Qt, можно попробовать сделать через setTransformOriginPoint (я так понял, она позволяет применять трансформации относительно заданной точки, т.е. задает, куда двигается объект после вращения).
Другой вариант, можно сбрасывать матрицу трансформации при помощи resetTransform, потом вращать при помощи rotate, затем двигать при помощи moveBy. 
Для начала советую попробовать setTransformOriginPoint. Не забудьте, что начальные координаты задаются в собственной системе координат объекта (относительно точки вращения).

Answer (score 0):

По задумке у каждого *QGraphicsItem* должна быть своя система координат, и функция *setRotation()* должна работать так, как Вы хотите.